# Hausdorff spaces from continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

I am trying to solve Exercise 2.35 in John M. Lee. *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, [p. 32](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZQVGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA32):

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Assume that for every $p\in X$ there exists a continuous function $f:~X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(0)=\{p\}$. Show that $X$ is Hausdorff.

(The inverse $f^{-1}$ here is implied as converse, not a bijective inverse.)

My thinking is that if we take the open subset $(-1;1)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ for each $f$ since the map is continuous we get open sets containing $p_i$, and it boils down to showing the intersection is empty. I can't quite follow this important part through.

Comment: Exercise 2.35. Suppose $X$ is a topological space, and for every $p \in X$ there exists a
continuous function $f:X \rightarrow R$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = p$. Show that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Sorry: I read *if* as *iff*. I’ll give you a hint in a minute.

Comment: I think it is good to include the source of the claim in the post. In this case it seems to be the book John M. Lee: *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, [p.32](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZQVGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA32).

Comment: What progress have you made?

Answer (score 2):

If $q\ne p$, let $f_p$ be a function $f:~X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f^{-1}(0)=\{p\}$ (this exists by assumption), and let $\alpha=f_p(q)>0$, and let $\epsilon=\frac{\alpha}2$. Consider the inverse images under $f_p$ of $(\leftarrow,\epsilon)$ and $(\epsilon,\to)$.

Comment: could you specify what you mean by $(\leftarrow, \epsilon)$ and $(\rightarrow, \epsilon)$ please

Comment: @sergey: You probably write them $(-\infty,\epsilon)$ and $(\epsilon,\infty)$; I prefer the arrow notation for rays, since it doesn’t suggest that there are objects $-\infty$ and $\infty$ out there somewhere.

Comment: ah, wow i must be really tired, can't believe didn't see something this simple. Thank you Brian

Comment: @sergey: It happens to all of us from time to time. You’re welcome!

Comment: while we are at it let me just ask you a set theoretic problem (i hate these...) How can i prove that a set is open iff every point has neighborhood contained in it? For the forward direction a really trivial thing to do is to consider the neighborhood to be the open set itself. But what about the other direction? can i say take the union of the neighborhoods for all the points in the set. They obviously exhaust the set, but since are all contained in it, the union is strictly equal the set and therefore the set is open?

Comment: @sergey: Yes, that works just fine, provided that your definition of *neighborhood* implies that nbhds are open. If your definition is that $N$ is a nbhd of $x$ provided that $x$ is in the interior of $N$, you should take for each $x\in U$ an *open* nbhd $N_x$ such that $x\in N_x\subseteq U$.

Comment: great, thanks again.

Comment: @sergey: My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

For each continuous function $f\colon X\to \mathbb R$, define $f^{\times}$ on $X\times X$ by $f^{\times}(p,q)=f(p)-f(q)$.

Consider the intersection: $$\bigcap_{f\colon X\to\mathbb R}\left(f^{\times}\right)^{-1}(\{0\})$$

Comment: If I am thinking correctly, this intersection $=\varnothing$ considering the hypothesis ($\{p\}-\{p\}=0$).

Comment: @majormaki The intersection is the diagonal subset $\{(x,x):x\in X\}$. One containment is straightforward; the other containment is a consequence of the hypothesis introduced in the question. Then, use the fact that the diagonal subset of $X\times X$ is closed if and only if $X$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p,q$ be distinct points in $X$.

Suppose there exists continuous $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(0)= \{ p \}$. Notice, for some $a>0$, $f^{-1}(-a,a) = U \subseteq X$ and $U$ is open in $X$ as it is the inverse image of an open set of real numbers. Of course, $p \in U$ is also clear from its construction.

Likewise, we have the existence of continuous $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for which $g^{-1}(0) = \{ q \}$. Moreover, for some $b>0$, $g^{-1}(-b,b) = V \subseteq X$ has $V$ open containing $q$.

So, there you have it, two open sets, each containing one of the points of interest. Now, we just need (possibly) to find smaller sets which are disjoint. How to do that?